# Why does Invoke-Command { net localgroup } fail?

Tags: powershell

I can successfully use `NET USE` and `NET USER` commands on the remote machine. Why not `NET LOCALGROUP`?

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Invoke-Command -ComputerName OTHERMACHINE -ScriptBlock { & NET LOCALGROUP }
System error 1312 has occurred.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 1312 has occurred.:String) [], Rem
   oteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : OTHERMACHINE

A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

Passing the /USER parameter produces a different error.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Invoke-Command -ComputerName OTHERMACHINE -ScriptBlock { & net localgroup /USER:THEDOM\theuser }
The option /USER:THEDOM\theuser is unknown.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The option /USE...son is unknown.:String) [], R
   emoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : OTHERMACHINE

The syntax of this command is:
NET LOCALGROUP
[groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
              groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
              groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3506.
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass the username with the net command (via /user:Domain\username) ?

Comment: @PeterSchneider - Yes, it produces a different error output.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147784/net-localgroup-administrators-equivalent-in-powershell)... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the double-hop problem.  You get the same error if you try to execute `net localgroup administrators` in a session created with `Enter-PSSession`: "System error 1312 has occurred." and "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

`net.exe` is trying to reauthenticate, but it can't reuse the credentials of the session.  You may have success using CredSSP, which requires some setup and, IIRC, may have security implications.  You'll have to [enable CredSSP on the remote system and local system, and then delegate correctly](https://serverfault.com/questions/277573/cannot-get-credssp-authentication-to-work-in-powershell).  Even then I'm seeing conflicting reports about this working.  There may even be [security policies](http://Network%20access:%20Do%20not%20allow%20storage%20of%20passwords%20and%20credentials%20for%20network%20authentication) preventing it.

Personally, I just wouldn't use `net.exe` at all.  That's too many hoops to jump through for something so basic.  You can [retrieve the members of a local group remotely via the ADSI provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147784/net-localgroup-administrators-equivalent-in-powershell), which is probably much easier and much more likely to work.

Comment: Yes, I had tried `Enter-PSSession` before and got the same results. It seems odd which `NET` commands work and which do not. Using [ADSI] will be more PoSh anyway. I will take this as the answer since there appears to be no better explanation.